# Redirect in nginx with extracting params from the url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a very long url's like:

```
https://mydomain.com/post/api/v5/apps/123/events/viewitem?data={"h_Authorization":"Basic wfwe","p_itemId":"**2342342**","p_userId":"vt.user.1385032845751.407012548","p_sessionId":"vt.sess.51c01e03ed14d94e30000003.1385623645321.318345957","p_tracking":{"vt_medium":"site-recommender","vt_campaign":"51de83a46e68d16d71000faf","vt_content":"51de83a46e68d16d71000faf","vt_source":"site"},"q_templates":"51de844d63d9f3782a001009:51de844d63d9f3782a001009,51de83a46e68d16d71000faf:51de83a46e68d16d71000faf"}&callback=__vt_jsonp_1
```

and need to redirect it using nginx to

/public/cache/products/**2342342**.json

So, the part before **2342342** in the original url it's always the same, and after it doesn't matter, as will be removed.

I've tried with:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/post\/api\/v5\/apps\/123\/events\/viewitem\?data={\"h_Authorization\":\"Basic wfwe\",\"p_itemId\":\"([0-9]+)(.*) public/cache/products/$1.json permanent;
}
```

and doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rewrite  ^/post/api/v5/apps/123/events/viewitem\?data=.*?p_itemId\"\:\"([0-9]+?)\".*?$ /public/cache/products/$1.json redirect;
```